# Dc.js Boxplot not creating outlines

Tags: dc.js

Why is dc.js boxplot not creating any outlines? I am just created a simplified code based on http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/boxplot-basic.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>

    <div id = 'boxch1'><br></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/crossfilter2@1.4.7/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://unpkg.com/dc@3/dc.js"></script>

    <script>
    let exp = [
         {"Expt":1, "Speed":8},
         {"Expt":1, "Speed":7},
         {"Expt":1, "Speed":9},
         {"Expt":1, "Speed":1},
         {"Expt":2, "Speed":8},
         {"Expt":2, "Speed":6},
         {"Expt":2, "Speed":8}];


          dc.config.defaultColors(d3.schemeSet1);
          var ndx = crossfilter(exp)
          runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Run;});
          runGroup = runDimension.group();
          experimentDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "exp-" + d.Expt;});

          speedArrayGroup = experimentDimension.group().reduce(
        function(p,v) {
          // keep array sorted for efficiency
          p.splice(d3.bisectLeft(p, v.Speed), 0, v.Speed);
          return p;
        },
        function(p,v) {
          p.splice(d3.bisectLeft(p, v.Speed), 1);
          return p;
        },
        function() {
          return [];
        }
          );

     var bp01 = dc.boxPlot("#boxch1");
        bp01
            .width(768)
            .height(480)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
            .dimension(experimentDimension)
            .group(speedArrayGroup)
            .elasticY(true)
            .elasticX(true);
    bp01.render()

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting the box outlines as in the chart drawn below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCASh.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for including a complete example.

These kinds of problems are usually because you are missing dc.css.

In dc.js, and D3 code in general, any static attributes of SVG elements that are not controlled by data can be specified in either JS code or in CSS. This includes axis lines, outlines, fonts, etc.

Generally it makes customization easier to use classnames and leave the static attributes to CSS. But you do need to include dc.css.